# Customizing set-payment-information-mixin.js with Mixin Error

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, mixins, alert

I am trying to convert the error message displayed in error container to alert box. To do so, I have created a mixin for

`set-payment-information-extended.js`
on path `Magento_Checkout\js\action\set-payment-information-extended.js`

the function i need to override from original payment-information-extended.js is

```
    return storage.post(
        serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload), true, 'application/json', headers
    ).fail(
        function (response) {
            errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
        }
    ).always(
        function () {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            _.each(hooks.afterRequestListeners, function (listener) {
                listener();
            });
        }
    );
```

Here, inside fail I would like to set an alert box using `Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert`

As the storage.post is a an ajax request, I need to modify only the fail case. I am not sure how to do it in mixin. While I try to call the return function using

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (response){

    }
});
```

It gives error `set-payment-information` is not a function. **Can someone guide me how to modify the ajax response and show error message in alert box instead of message container if response is fail?**

The whole code for file `set-payment-information-extended.js` can be found in `vendor/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/`

I am adding the whole code below for reference:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/set-payment-hooks'
], function (quote, urlBuilder, storage, errorProcessor, customer, getTotalsAction, fullScreenLoader, _, hooks) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Filter template data.
     *
     * @param {Object|Array} data
     */
    var filterTemplateData = function (data) {
        return _.each(data, function (value, key, list) {
            if (_.isArray(value) || _.isObject(value)) {
                list[key] = filterTemplateData(value);
            }

            if (key === '__disableTmpl') {
                delete list[key];
            }
        });
    };

    return function (messageContainer, paymentData, skipBilling) {
        var serviceUrl,
            payload,
            headers = {};

        paymentData = filterTemplateData(paymentData);
        skipBilling = skipBilling || false;
        payload = {
            cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
            paymentMethod: paymentData
        };

        /**
         * Checkout for guest and registered customer.
         */
        if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/set-payment-information', {
                cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
            });
            payload.email = quote.guestEmail;
        } else {
            serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/set-payment-information', {});
        }

        if (skipBilling === false) {
            payload.billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
        }

        fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

        _.each(hooks.requestModifiers, function (modifier) {
            modifier(headers, payload);
        });

        return storage.post(
            serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload), true, 'application/json', headers
        ).fail(
            function (response) {
                errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
            }
        ).always(
            function () {
                fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                _.each(hooks.afterRequestListeners, function (listener) {
                    listener();
                });
            }
        );
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is challenging because the code that you are trying to override is within one very long function. The only mixin option I see would require re-implementing the entire function, which means maintaining compatibility for a bunch of functionality that is only peripherally related to your goal.

Another option is to use a mixin to override `Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor`, which is much shorter and more focused. You may need to parse the incoming `response` and `messageContainer` if you want to selectively display an alert instead of allowing the default behavior.

The mixin code would be something like:

```
define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function (wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (errorProcessor) {
        errorProcessor.process = wrapper.wrapSuper(errorProcessor.process, function (response, messageContainer) {
            
            /*
               Your custom code, which might want to exit before the subsequent call to this._super()
            */

            this._super(response, messageContainer);
        });

        return errorProcessor;
    };
});
```

The registration would be somethign like:

```
'config': {
    'mixins': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor': {
            'Your_Extension/js/model/error-processor-mixin': true
        },
    }
},
```

Comment: I need to work on response only for storage.post and not entire function. I don't think rewriting entire function is needed.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to alter how storage.post is handled without copy/pasting the entire function that surrounds it into a mixin.